# Firestore nested gets using callbacks getting empty results on initial call

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, callback, google-cloud-firestore

So here's my scenario:
I have three separate calls to firestore in their own classes.  All three of the calls are nested within each other's callback and in the last callback I do all my work.  When I trigger this stack, my Admin object will have already existed while my users list and books list would be created as this stack listens for an update.  If data doesn't exist in the database and we create an entry the callback doesn't report a book (I do get Admin and User objects however).  However, if we re-open the app and data already exists in the database then the callback reports something.  After this, anytime I add a user/book then the list updates properly.

Note: these are realTime listeners so as soon as a user/book is added then we should see the update.

Here are my classes:

```
public class FirebaseGetThisAdmin {

    //firebase objects
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore mDbase;

    private Activity activity;

    private Admin admin;
    private String adminID;

    //default constructor
    public FirebaseGetThisAdmin() {
    }

    public FirebaseGetThisAdmin(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public interface FirestoreCallback {
        void onCallback(Admin admin);
    }

    public void readDataRTUpdate(final FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback) {

        //firebase new instances
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDbase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //get admin email address and user name from Auth and set textInput fields to them
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            adminID = mAuth.getUid();
        }

        final DocumentReference docRef = mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID);
        docRef.addSnapshotListener(activity, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }

                String source = snapshot != null && snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
                        ? "Local" : "Server";

                if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                    admin = new Admin();
                    admin = snapshot.toObject(Admin.class);
                    //pass variables to the callback
                    firestoreCallback.onCallback(admin);
                    Log.d(TAG, source + " data: " + snapshot.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, source + " data: null");
                }
            }
        });
    }
} 

 public class FirebaseGetUsers {

    //firebase objects
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore mDbase;

    private Activity activity;

    private String adminID;

    //default constructor
    public FirebaseGetUsers() {
    }

    public FirebaseGetUsers(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        //firebase new instances
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDbase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            adminID = mAuth.getUid();
        }
    }

    public interface FirestoreCallback {
        void onCallback(List<User> users);
    }

    public void readDataRTUpdate(final FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback) {
        mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID).collection("users")
                .addSnapshotListener(activity, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (value != null) {
                            int i = 0;
                            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                                users.add(document.toObject(User.class));
                                Log.d(TAG, "User: " + users.get(i).toString());
                                i++;
                            }
                            firestoreCallback.onCallback(users);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Document updated.");
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Next:

```
 public class FirebaseGetUsers {

    //firebase objects
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore mDbase;

    private Activity activity;

    private String adminID;

    //default constructor
    public FirebaseGetUsers() {
    }

    public FirebaseGetUsers(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        //firebase new instances
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDbase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            adminID = mAuth.getUid();
        }
    }

    public interface FirestoreCallback {
        void onCallback(List<User> users);
    }

    public void readDataRTUpdate(final FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback) {
        mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID).collection("users")
                .addSnapshotListener(activity, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (value != null) {
                            int i = 0;
                            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                                users.add(document.toObject(User.class));
                                Log.d(TAG, "User: " + users.get(i).toString());
                                i++;
                            }
                            firestoreCallback.onCallback(users);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Document updated.");
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Next:

```
   public class FirebaseGetBooks {

    //firebase objects
    private FirebaseFirestore mDbase;

    private Activity activity;

    private String groupID;

    //default constructor
    public FirebaseGetBooks() {
    }

    public FirebaseGetBooks(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        //firebase new instances
        mDbase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        FirebaseGetGroupID firebaseGetGroupID = new FirebaseGetGroupID(activity);
        groupID = firebaseGetGroupID.getGroupID();
    }


    public interface FirestoreCallback {
        void onCallback(List<Book> books);
    }


    public void readDataRTUpdate(final FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback) {
        mDbase.collection("books").whereEqualTo("groupID", groupID)
                .addSnapshotListener(activity, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (value != null) {
                            int i = 0;
                            List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                                books.add(document.toObject(Book.class));
                                Log.d(TAG, "Book: " + books.get(i).toString());
                                i++;
                            }
                            firestoreCallback.onCallback(books);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Document updated.");
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

And finally my call in MainActivity:

```
    firebaseGetUsers.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetUsers.FirestoreCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(final List<User> users) {
                firebaseGetBooks.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetBooks.FirestoreCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCallback(final List<Book> books) {
                        firebaseGetThisAdmin.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetThisAdmin.FirestoreCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCallback(Admin admin) {
                                //processing all code here.
                                //books are empty!!
                                System.out.println("books: " + books.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A little bit more information. It appears that this issue only happens when the local cache is empty. Once the local cache is set then the issue goes away.

Comment: Your code is fine. Why would be the cache empty? Have you set the offline persistence to false?

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex.  I'm not changing the persistence setting for offline cache, and for Android I know it's on by default.  What I'm referring to is the first time a snapShot listener is requesting data from the database, in that moment, the local cache won't have any information until it is stored.  Then on consecutive updates data would be available locally.  I'm actually speculating that this is what is happening as I can't explain it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was able to finally solve this issue.  It had nothing to do with the Firestore nested callbacks.  If you notice in the getBooks class, I'm referencing a groupID value.  This value represents this Admin's account (holds reference to both users and other admins).  Since this value never changes throughout the life of the account, I'm storing it locally in shared preferences so I can reduce database get() commands.  However, it appears that on first login, the variable groupID isn't getting set quickly enough before we try to use it to access books from the database.

So, the net result is that books isn't able to find any documents since the variable isn't set yet.

My fix for this is two-folded.  When the admin creates their account, the groupID is created when we create our first document reference.  At this point we store it immediately to sharedPrefs.  No need to try to get it from the database at this point, since it created and accessible locally.  Second, I nested the Firestore get() groupID callback inside of our Firestore sign in method.  So anything that gets executed when the user logs in happens AFTER we retrieve this value (for proper cleanup purposes the groupID is cleared from sharedPrefs on every logout).